# Lookup Matching Value in Other Dataframe and Return ID

Tags: r, lookup-tables, grepl

I have a dataframe (relationship) in R containing relationships between animals:

```
animal1 | animal2 | relationship  
dog       cat       friendly
cat       dog       amicable
pig       goose     mean
```

I have another dataframe (animal) containing info about each animal:

```
id | animal | count   
1   dog       2      
2   cat       5       
3   pig       1     
4   goose     2
```

I want to replace the animals in the first dataframe with the values of their IDs in the second data frame, i.e.

```
animal1 | animal2 | relationship  
1       | 2       | friendly
2       | 1       | amicable
3       | 4       | mean
```

How do I do this?  So far, I am able to use grepl to do this for an individual item, i.e.

```
which(grepl(relationship$animal1[3],animal$id)) >>>> 2
```

How can I apply this generally over the whole relationship data frame and replace the animal1/animal2 columns with the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`.  We `gather` the data to 'long' format, `left_join` with the second dataset, change the 'animal' column with the values of 'id' and `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, animal, animal1:animal2) %>%
        left_join(df2[-3]) %>% 
        mutate(animal = id) %>% 
        select(-id)  %>% 
        spread(key, animal) %>%
        select(names(df1))
```

---

Or another option without doing the reshaping in `base R` would be to loop through the first two column, do a `match` with the 'animal column of 'df2' and get the corresponding 'id's, assign it back to the columns of interest

```
df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], function(x) df2$id[match(x, df2$animal)])
df1
#   animal1 animal2 relationship
#1       1       2     friendly
#2       2       1     amicable
#3       3       4         mean
```

---

Or the similar approach with `dplyr` would be

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(matches("animal")), funs(df2$id[match(., df2$animal)]))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun for the multiple options.  I used lapply and this worked perfectly!